# z-index issue with IE AND FireFox on WordPress page?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I've got some jQuery running after a WordPress page loads.

```
jQuery('[class="image responsive"]').append('<div id="switch"><img src="/js/off2.png"></div>');
jQuery("#switch").css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'left': '2%',
    'top': '40%',
    'z-index': '9'
});
jQuery('#switch img').click(function() {
    //some code that doesn't run
})
```

The code runs fine and the click action fires on Chrome. However, when tested on IE and FireFox, nothing happens on the click (the #switch is appended and styled properly, however). I've seen z-index bugs on Internet Explorer going back all the way to 2009 through 2014, but neither IE 'nor FireFox behaves how I expected it to. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you tried to use the inspector to see if it is the actual z-index that's causing the issue?

Comment: I have not, but I can't seem to find any other potential issue with the code. Suggestions are welcome, as I can't seem to find out what could be causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use .on() when the element is created dynamically.

```
$('body').on('click', '#switch img', function(){
  // Some code
});
```

Comment: Should have added, I already tried this.

Comment: The problem is probably elsewhere then. At least I can get the click event fire properly on the image click.  http://jsfiddle.net/nadsojob/

Answer (score 1):

Hello it's working fine here plz check code here.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('[class="image responsive"]').append('<div id="switch"><img src="/js/off2.png"></div>');
    jQuery("#switch").css({
      'position': 'absolute',
      'left': '2%',
      'top': '40%',
      'z-index': '9'
  });
  jQuery('#switch img').click(function() {
 alert('test');
    //some code that doesn't run
  });
});
```

you need to add document.ready and it's work.